# Does SqlDataReader take into account the NonClustered Index on database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, indexing, sqldatareader

**Does c# "SqlDataReader" take into account the NonClustered index existing on the database?**

For example I created the index on the database:

```
Create nonClustered Index x1 on [MyDB].[dbo].[Customers] (CustomerID)
```

Then in the c# code I do the following:

```
String sqlQry="Select CustomerId from [MyDB].[dbo].[Customers] where CustomerID=123456";
SqlCommand cmdFindCustomer = new SqlCommand(sqlQry, SQLConnectionObj);
SqlDataReader r = cmdFindCustomer.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with `SqlDataReader`. A query's a query, no matter where it comes from. Will the optimizer use the index you created? Very probably, yes. But how client code executes the query is irrelevant.

Comment: As stated.  No relationship whatsoever.

Comment: Non clustered index is to make sure a unique key(id) is create in a multi-user environment.  Non clustered is when you have more than one Server for a database.  Usually you will append a fix number to the clustered index so each server ids will be different.  Server one appends 100001 + Non Clustered index.  Server two appends 100002 + Non clustered index.

Comment: Ah! the query **does use** the index. Thanks Jeroen.

Comment: @jdweng You are absolutely nowhere near the correct answer. Clustered/non-clustered indexes have absolutely nothing to do with multiple servers. Please read over [this page from the msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx) for a actual description of what they are. The thing you are describing is [identity range management](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suhde/2010/03/21/inf-automatic-identity-range-management-with-merge-replication-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005-2008/)

Answer (score 2):

> Does c# "SqlDataReader" take into account the NonClustered index
>   existing on the database?

No, the object has no knowledge of the indexes.

Assuming that your question is, when are non-clustered indexes going to be utilized in a query plan with SQL Server, it depends. The optimizer is usually much smarter than the rest of us, but if you want you can force the use of an index with a hint. This is, of course, if you check your query plan and it isn't being used.

To see if your index is being used (GUI route), click the Display Actual Execution Plan in SQL Server Management Studio and run your query. It will be on a separate tab and has operations displayed in a format that you should read right to left, down to up. Look for an operation of hopefully an index seek on your index. If you don't see that, it isn't being used. What are the next steps?

Do your research on index architecture. MSDN has great read ups on how to design and implement good indexes. Some other resources to check out are great consultants within the industry such as Paul Randal and Brent Ozar.

Comment: I removed my no-longer reverent comments

Answer (score 0):

No. The Query engine of SQL Server will determine what is or are the best indexes he will use for get your data.

Using the SqlDataReader object not has influnce on use of a key.